# How to increase sales on educational website and how to engage people on forum to talk about/answer on relevant topic?

Tags: user-engagement, participation, promotion

I am working with an educational website. Where people use to ask question related to study abroad. Our motive of this website is to get help from the people who have gone or experience with that topic/subject. So how I can involve people to answer and share their experience?

Comment: The text of your question is not about sales - please edit that out of your title, because it would make this *two* questions (you can always ask another one about the sales).

Comment: Is there anything more that you can add that is specific to your site? Because currently it is now just "How can I grow my forum about studying abroad" and questions of this type [have been asked here before](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+grow).